# Compile and run C++ code in single key stroke using vim in Mac OS

Tags: c++, vim, osx-snow-leopard

I am using Mac OS X version 10.6.8. Is there any helpful script to compile and run my c++ file from inside vim using single command?

Comment: Do a shell command then make?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :<C-U>make %:r && ./%:r<CR>
```

This will run `make` with the C++ file (less its extension) as the target and run the file in the same directory with that target's name.

See the following `:help` for more information...

- [`nnoremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3annoremap): Create a normal-mode mapping
- [`<F5>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html#<F5>): for <kbd>F5</kbd> (other function keys are available)
- [`<C-U>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-U): clear the command-line
- [`make`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3amake): call [`'makeprg'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27), which is `make` by default
- [`%:r`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%25%3ar): root of the current filename (extension removed)
- [`<CR>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_<CR>): execute all this

If you want this for all Vim sessions, place this into your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <F5> :<C-U>make %:r && ./%:r<CR>
```

#### Update:

You may also find the [SingleCompile](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) Vim script to be handy for C++ and many other languages besides.

Comment: :help makeprg might be useful too.

Comment: Can this be placed verbatim into .vimrc without the preceding ":"?